# Is it possible to create a Heroku review app from a Bitbucket pull request

Tags: git, heroku, github, bitbucket

I've been using this feature with GitHub, but it seems there's no way to get a review app running when the codebase is hosted on BitBucket.

Is there a way of getting around this limitation?

Comment: do you use forks or branches for the pull requests?

Answer (score 2):

Tested on bitbucket server v4.3.2 on premises, not on the cloud

First - you need to know the `pull request` number. The `pull request` `ref` looks like this

```
b36ccdc90928827b4ce316aa10cb3b7464c8d672    refs/pull-requests/${pull_request_id}/from
42644bf1ae8fdc773e86efa3686e85e671c48504    refs/pull-requests/${pull_request_id}/merge
```

The `b36ccdc90928827b4ce316aa10cb3b7464c8d672   refs/pull-requests/${pull_request_id}/from` `ref` points to the head of source branch and the `42644bf1ae8fdc773e86efa3686e85e671c48504 refs/pull-requests/${pull_request_id}/merge` `ref` point to the merged code.

So the following will checkout the pull request

```
git fetch origin refs/pull-requests/${pull_request_id}/merge
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

And now you can do whatever you want with this code